# Console output garbled - Cisco 1812 Router

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios

Console output became garbled/scrambled during the reset procedure using ROMon, making it unviewable, and has been ever since on this device. See screenshot.[image: console output]

Have tried various suggested baud rates with no success. Console cable and COM port are also OK, (have tested with other devices subsequently).

This is a secondhand router I purchased from Ebay for a home CCNA LAB.

Comment: What baud rate, data bits, parity, stop bits, etc. are you using?

Comment: 9600, 8,none,1 respectively

Comment: Prior to the reset command being issued I had a good connection. It was between stage 4 and 5 of [this procedure](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/11856/resetting-router-factory-default-removing-startup-configuration-file) that it garbled.

Comment: What value did you set the configuration register?

Comment: I entered      confreg 0x2142

Comment: Are you absolutely sure; no typos? For example, accidentally setting it to `0x2124` would change the baud rate to `19200`.

Comment: Just tried restarting the device with 19200 baud set in puTTY. No output displayed at all.

Comment: That was just an example. The config-register will change things if you had a typo. It can change the baud rate, if the router tries to boot from the network, etc.

Comment: Im happy to lose any configs if I can reset the baud to a known value. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to power cycle the Router and try following baud rate speeds: 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200. set flow control none, data bits 8, parity none, stop bits 1. Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: 1200 did it! I had tried this earlier with no positive result. I notice the output scrolls quite slowly now. I assume this is as a result of the lower baud.

Comment: Please try with 2400 and 4800 baud rate, and see if it works, and if it works then try to upgrade the IOS in Router.

Comment: Only 1200 works currently. I will try resetting the config-register value again tomorrow. As Ron suggested above I may have made a typo whe I first did it.

Comment: baud will affect character display rates. The 8n1 means that you are sending 9bits per character (8bits +  0 parity + 1 stop).  1200 baud / 9bits = 133 characters/second. If you were connected over a really lossy connection you might have to use 8e2 which would be 8bits +  1 parity bit (which makes the total previous byte Even by adding a 0 or 1) + 2 stop bits = for a total of 13 or 92cps. If you knew that you wouldn't need bytes over 128 then you could go 7bit data and at absolutely best go 7n0 for 171cps @ 1200 baud.